# Using two-dimensional massive in function C++

Tags: c++, function

When I compile this code(below) it gives me an error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:46:37: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[n]' to 'int**' for argument '4' to 'void dfs(int, std::vector<int>&, int, int**)'
     dfs(1, used, n, Adjacency_matrix);
```

As I understand situation its because of calling two-dimensional massive in function uncorrectly. What i need to correct in this code so that function accepts my massive.

p.s. Sorry for my english :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

void dfs(int i, std::vector <int> &used, int n, int (&Adjacency_matrix)[n][n]) {
    used[i] = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        if ((Adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1) && (used[j] == 0))
            dfs(j, used, n, Adjacency_matrix);
    }
}

double distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return sqrt((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2));
}

int main() {
    int n, k;
    std::cin >> n >> k;

    int coordinates[n][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> coordinates[i][1];
        std::cin >> coordinates[i][2];
    }

    int Adjacency_matrix[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (i == j)
                Adjacency_matrix[i][i] = 0;
            if ((i != j) && (distance(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2], coordinates[j][1], coordinates[j][2]) <= k))
                Adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 1;
            if ((i != j) && (distance(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2], coordinates[j][1], coordinates[j][2]) > k))
                Adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    std::vector <int> used;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        used.push_back(0);

    dfs(1, used, n, Adjacency_matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (used[i] == 0)
            std::cout << "NO";
            exit(0);
    }
    std::cout << "YES";
}
```

Comment: I'd start by not using non-standard VLA's in C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dsf` function declaration is wrong. Use

```
template<size_t N>
void dfs(int i, std::vector <int> &used, int (&Adjacency_matrix)[N][N]) 
{ ... }
```

to capture the size of the array passed by reference.
Next, you cannot use variable sized arrays in standard C++,

```
int Adjacency_matrix[n][n];
```

is not valid, unless `n` is a `const` or `constexpr`. Hence, you cannot read it from `cin`. If you want dynamic size, use `std::vector` or pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn this code:

```
int Adjacency_matrix[n][n];
```

into standard C++.  In standard C++, you cannot declare arrays using a variable as the number of entries.

You can use `std::vector` to produce a 2 dimensional array of int.

```
#include <vector>
//...
typedef std::vector<int> Int1D;
typedef std::vector<Int1D> Int2D;
//...
void dfs(int i, Int1D &used, int n, Int2D& Adjacency_matrix) // 
{
//...
}

int main()
{
    //...
    Int2D coordinates(n, Int1D(2));       // replacement for int coordinates[n][2]
    //...
    Int2D Adjacency_matrix(n, Int1D(n));  // substitute for int Adjacency_matrix[n][n]
    //...
    dfs(1, used, n, Adjacency_matrix);
    //...
}
```